# Android Bottom Nav Bar Icon Distortion

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am experiencing a mysterious issue. In the Android Bottom Nav Bar I changed the default 3 icons, and am trying to use 4 icons.

The icons are now distorted. There's some sort of blank overlay covering the bottom of the icons. All the code checks out, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

[image: Icon Distortion]

I found and tried this on StackOverflow to no avail...

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationView menuView = (BottomNavigationView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        ((Field) shiftingMode).setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            item.setShifting(false);
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
    }
}
```

I tried adjusting the XML layout views as best as I know how.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using '**com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07**' version for this.

i have added this in xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

I have added below line in onCreate of Activity as well

```
navigation.itemIconTintList = null
```

This is working fine. there's no distortion for icons. Try to add a Fixed height for nav_view.

Hope it fixes your issue.